# Is it possible to use PIP mode which is not for videos?

Tags: html, picture-in-picture

I want to show a div class as PiP(Picture in Picture). 
I have googled a lot, but only how to enable in videos, not a custom div.

At my environment, js, CSS and HTML can be used. A div that I want to use PiP changes second by second.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you want to do and how pictures are related to this.

Answer (score 12):

Nope PiP is available for <video> only.

What you could do though is to stream a <canvas> in a <video> and use PiP there.
You can now draw whatever you want in this <canvas>, and even [reproduce HTML content](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');
const source = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = source.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "50px Arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
anim();

const stream = source.captureStream();
target.srcObject = stream;

const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
if( target.requestPictureInPicture ) {
  btn.onclick = e => target.requestPictureInPicture();
}
else {
  btn.disabled = true;
}

function anim() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, source.width, source.height );
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillText( new Date().toTimeString().split(' ')[0], source.width / 2, source.height / 2 );
  requestAnimationFrame( anim );
}
```

```html
<video id="target" controls muted autoplay></video>
<button id="btn">request PiP</button>
```

Comment: Can I suggest `setTimeout( anim , 1000);` instead of `requestAnimationFrame`,  to illustrate that the canvas can in fact be altered at a bespoke rate, without affecting streaming

Comment: @unsynchronized not really. After some times, the browser will "mute" the MediaStream, and the video's timer will be paused too (at least in Chrome, other browsers have other behaviors).  This is meant to be a general demo, and in the general case, rAF is to be preferred to render an animation on screen. And in the particular case of a timer with seconds precision, you want an interval with less than a second, because any timer is always late, so using the same precision as what you show, you'll show it late.

Comment: So you are saying that each frame is rendered in response to the callback rather than streaming a frame from buffer memory at the stream's encoding rate?

Comment: @unsynchronized yes, kind of. Unfortunately the specs are quite unclear here, see [this issue](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-fromelement/issues/94) and one linked from there. But the observable behavior is indeed that until you perform a new drawing on the canvas, the MediaStream won't receive any frame. After the next painting, a new frame will be pushed with the correct timestamp. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaw63fz0/1/), in Chrome, the first video will have its timestamp stuck at 00:00:00 until you click in the page, and the second video won't show anything before that.

Comment: That actually sounds like it could be quite useful, if you don't want a high frame rate.