# Are android, ios pip mode is only for the video playback?

Tags: android, ios, picture-in-picture

I am a 5+ years web developer and I am trying to develop an app which supports pip mode using react-native.

Since I have only a minimum understanding of app development, I've read through the android documentation but still I want to ask 2 things.

According to the android pip documentation (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/picture-in-picture),

> PiP is a special type of multi-window mode mostly used for video playback

**1. Is pip mode only for the video playback?**

What I want to do is just to show a certain UI (character) in the right bottom corner of the screen. It definitely is not a video, so I am curious if it is okay to proceed with this approach (pip mode)

**2. If pip mode is not only for the video playback, is pip mode switches app into the background mode?**

While showing a certain UI in pip mode, still I want to do some calculation in my app.
But as I know, if an app goes into the background mode, there comes a limit calling an external APIs. so if it is in background mode, I will just do the client-side calculation.

I am sorry for asking this question for the native app developers if it is too basic.

Anyway, appreciate in advance for your help.

P.S)

I found this question, [Is it possible to use PIP mode which is not for videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61301087/is-it-possible-to-use-pip-mode-which-is-not-for-videos)

but I think this is only for the web.

if it is for the video also in the app, is it possible to execute some calculations while playing videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android

1)No.  PIP allows one app to display on top of another in a little window.  So it doesn't need to be video.  However you wouldn't use PIP within your app-  you'd use it to display your app on top of other apps.  If you want to display a character in the bottom right of the screen when your app is on, you'd just add a view there to your layout.

2)No, a PIP app is in the foreground.

Comment: thank god. appreciate for your answer. but I am surprised to know that it is in the foreground. As I know, youtube can be switched into the pip mode, but can simultaneously be used with the google navigation. Is it possible to execute 2 different foreground apps at the same time?

Comment: And I also added some extras to my question. It seems that pip in web only supports video tags. From what you've said, I assume there's a lot difference in pip implementation strategy btw the web and the app.

Comment: pip in web is  feature of the browser.  Native pip is something completely different, its OS level  (and iOS may or may not have it, I have no clue).

Comment: appreciate for your answer. I'll take your answer. anyway, could you also answer the first comment I ask? "Is it possible to execute 2 different foreground apps at the same time?"